# What containers were used for food prior to the industrial era?

Tags: economy, food, everyday-life

Today, when you go shopping, most of the food is kept in plastic or paper containers (or tin cans).

In the everyday life, what types of containers were used to sell, transport and keep food before plastic and before the industrial era?

Comment: Pottery (amphora), barrels, and wineskins mostly - which is why archaeologists know so much about pottery, as it is the only one of the three relatively imperishable.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - The problem with barrels in ancient tombs is that they are always the first thing wandering adventurers want to break. ;-)

Comment: No metal or glass or cardboard or leather or fabric ?

Comment: @T.E.D.: I am not averse to cracking open a barrel or two myself from time to time.

Comment: @Xoff: Thank you for the accept - but maybe it is a bit early; fast accepts tend to reduce the number of eyeballs that see your question. If you really want the best possible answer, I suggest waiting a day or two to see all the answers that get submitted.

Comment: ok, I'm used to the math section where it's a little bit different. I'll wait a few before accepting, thanks !

Comment: (OP forgot canning)

Comment: @Xoff glass is a relatively recent invention, and originally would have been too expensive (it's rather labour intensive to make by hand).

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Comment: Among the Brazilian tribes first contacted in the XX century, one of the the most requested modern items on the first contacts were modern recipients to store food.  Less weight (important for semi-nomads) and good protection from insects and the elements (besides the very nasty insects, it rains a lot on the amazon). And they were quick to realize that when seeing civilized men's gear for the first time.

Comment: @Luiz very interesting detail. Perhaps read "receptacle" for "recipient".

Comment: Additionally to the answers, the precedent of the plastic or paper bag was the basket. I remember shopping groceries with a straw basket a few decades ago.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pottery (amphora), barrels, and wineskins mostly - which is why archaeologists know so much about pottery, as it is the only one of the three relatively imperishable.

Paper was relatively expensive by todays standards until the early 20th century (and glass more so as only hand-blown glass was known) thus would have been used only to store relatively pricey items such as spices and medicines.

Metal tins (not tin cans!) were useful because a very tight seal could be obtained rom metal-on-metal contact, but this really only becomes common in Europe after the development of [improved sheet-rolling technology](http://www.ssab.com/Brands/Prelaq/Products/What-is-Prelaq/Brief-history-of-sheet-steel/) in the early 19th century. (Think tobacco containers, and their *almost air-tight* seal.)

Tin cans followed a few decades later, in time for the Arctic and Antarctic expeditions of the late 19th century.

As an example of the sometimes dramatic price changes that have ensued from cheap electric power, consider the cutlery at Louis Napoleon's coronation. The most favoured guests were provide with the *even-more-expensive-than-platinum* cutlery, manufactured from **aluminum**. Only the hoi-polloi were provided with silver cutlery!

Comment: you forgot leather bladders (and yes, washed out animal bladders) for storing liquids (mostly short term), and large plant leaves (think banana leaves) for storing solids, both of which are still used to this day.

Comment: @jwenting: Such is usually referred to as a *wineskin*, or occasionally a *bota*, and as you point out is a washed-out animal bladder reinforced on the outside by a sewn leather bag.: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bota_bag

Comment: yes, that's the word I was looking for. Often used as well by troops on the move to store water rations for the day's march (easier than sipping from a wooden barrel strapped on your back).

Comment: I did not know about aluminum. Thank you for the answer !

Comment: The top cap of the Washington Monument is Aluminum because it was more precious than gold at the time.

Answer (score 2):

Before plastic, most of liquids were sold in paper containers or glass bottles (paper packs for liquids appeared in 20th century though). Solid food was sold in paper envelopes or boxes, metal boxes, foil or in natural envelopes (guts, leafs).

Sometimes people were required to come with their own volumes to buy a liquid or a semi-liquid, with large quantities stored in wood/metal barrels.

Comment: In fact I was wondering if glass, paper and metal was something common enough during middle age to be used as food containers, or if people had to use more mundane materials like potteries…

Comment: @Xoff most liquids those times were distributed into the buyer's containers whatever he comes with (usually, pottery I think).

Comment: The 17th century antiquary John Aubrey regretted that old manuscripts were sometimes used to line pie-dishes (as we use greaseproof paper in cake tins). That shows how scarce paper was.

Answer (score 2):

Modern food packaging came much later than the "industrial era". The food like fruits and vegetables was sold without any packaging. Meat, butter, cheese, sausage etc. was wrapped in paper by the seller at the time you bought it, liquids were sold in glass bottles. This was the usual practice, for example, in Soviet Union until it collapsed.
Tin cans and conservation were invented in XIX century. Large quantities of liquids were preserved in wood barrels.